# How do I view and halt running Google Apps Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script that is running that I want to stop. I've tried deauthorizing it but that didn't work. Instead, it still tries to perform its actions, with each action (running every 5 minutes), failing due to lack of authorization. I want to halt the process entirely but I don't know how. Is there some way to view all running Google Apps Script processes for a given Google account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open any script in the script editor,go to the resource menu / triggers / all my triggers , choose the one you want to delete and delete it...

Comment: "All your triggers" item has moved to the *Edit* menu